# How to extract node information conditional to the information of a sibling node using python?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

I have a list with `personId`of interest:

```
agents = {'id': ['20','32','12']}
```

Then I have an XML file with household characteristics:

```
<households
    <household id="980921">
        <members>
            <personId refId="5"/>
            <personId refId="15"/>
            <personId refId="20"/>
        </members>
        <income currency="CHF" period="month">
                8000.0
        </income>
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="numberOfCars" class="java.lang.String" >2</attribute>
        </attributes>

    </household>
    <household id="980976">
        <members>
            <personId refId="2891"/>
            <personId refId="100"/>
            <personId refId="2044"/>
        </members>
        <income currency="CHF" period="month">
                8000.0
        </income>
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="numberOfCars" class="java.lang.String" >1</attribute>
        </attributes>

    </household>
    <household id="980983">
        <members>
            <personId refId="11110"/>
            <personId refId="32"/>
            <personId refId="34"/>
        </members>
        <income currency="CHF" period="month">
                10000.0
        </income>
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="numberOfCars" class="java.lang.String" >0</attribute>
        </attributes>

    </household>
</households>
```

What I want is to have a data frame, which shows me the `income` of the households, which house a `member`which belongs to the list of `agents` which are of interest. Something like this (a plus would be an additional column which indicates the count of members of the household which houses a person of interest):

```
personId    income
20          8000.0
32          10000.0
```

My approach did not really get too far. I have difficulties how to filter for the `members`and then access info from a "sibling" node. My output is an empty data frame.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

with open(xml) as fd:
    root = ET.parse(fd).getroot()

xpath_fmt = 'household/members/personId[@refId="{}"]/income'
rows = []
for pid in agents['id']:
    xpath = xpath_fmt.format(pid)
    r = root.findall(xpath)
    for res in r:
        rows.append([pid, res.text])
d = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['personId', 'income'])
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Can you use `BeautifulSoup`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've corrected my question. The output is an empty data frame, not an error

Comment: @AndrejKesely, I'm sorry, but Im not familiar with ```BeautifulSoup```. I'm open to any new approach that works:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, here is the solution using BeautifulSoup (`xml_txt` is your XML text from the question):

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

agents = {'id': ['20','32','12']}

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_txt, 'xml')  #xml_txt is your XML text from the question

css_selector = ','.join('household > members > personId[refId="{}"]'.format(i) for i in agents['id'])

data = {'personId':[], 'income':[]}
for person in soup.select(css_selector):
    data['personId'].append( person['refId'] )
    data['income'].append( person.find_parent('household').find('income').get_text(strip=True) )

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  personId   income
0       20   8000.0
1       32  10000.0
```